# Is it possible to use chests for world spawn in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I love playing on minecraft servers but I don't like switching through worlds by using the /world command, is it possible to use chests as a GUI and show different worlds, games, and warps on spigot/bukkit.

I hope im not advertising but I've seen a similar technique used in got pvp servers and hope I can use it on a Normal Spigot server(I can not tell you the link but if you ask I can tell it to you.).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

There is actually a way to do something like this, in fact many servers allow you to do this such as  Hypixel and CubeCraft. Although these servers can warp to other mini-servers within it real easily, its thanks to plug-ins like Multiverse. Multiverse and others like it allow server operators to simply make multiple worlds without /world. Pretty much these plug-ins will help you make new worlds so maybe you can make a lobby for your arcade or a PvP arena and easily access it. This plug-in will also allow you to move throughout these servers with just the click of a compass or something of the sort. All you have to do is click and/or right-click, depending on the type of plug-in you have, and a GUI will appear. :) You can add items to this GUI and by simply clicking on one of them you can be teleported to that specific world. Some plug-ins even run a certain command not every player really knows about from just clicking a certain item. For example on Hypixel you can insert a skull or a hat into your helmet area in your inventory if you've unlocked it. This cannot be done by commands on the server. Even if it could it might be easier to access the hats that way anyways. Hopefully you can find a plug-in of the sort. I am not very familiar with any of them to a certain extent, but I do know Multiverse can do something of the sort. I hope this helped you and I'm sorry if it didn't. Please feel free to ask me any further questions as I might be able to answer more of them or any follow up questions :)

Thanks :)
The King

Comment: Apparently, Thomas already has the Multiverse or Multiworld installed.

Also, this: `Please feel free to ask me any further questions as I might be able to answer more of them or any follow up questions :)` isn't the point of this site. We try to create some kind of wiki for everyone having this problem in the future. Offering personal help for a single user doesnt really help (explains the downvotes i hope)